# How to install syndesis (stable) on minishift

Tags: syndesis

I'm trying to install syndesis on minishift following the official guides.
Installed minishift on ubuntu, no issues. Next I've tried

- ./syndesis minishift --install. In the end it says I have to run local dev builds for sysdesis-server syndesis-ui, etc
- ./syndesis build --app-images but got some dependency errors
- Run syndesis quickstart. All the pods are up except syndesis-server. It doesn't start due to error like UnknownHostException: syndesis-db in the migration bean
- Also tried ./syndesis minishift --install --tag 1.8.12 to install stable version but not sure if I'm doing it right cause no success
  Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. We moved to use an Operator to do the installation and it caused a bunch of installation issues. If you have minishift installed then on Linux or Mac you should be able to get Syndesis installed using

bash <(curl -sL https://syndes.is/start)

See also: https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis-quickstarts/blob/master/README.md#3-install-syndesis

It uses the `syndesis` bash command line tool from (https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis/blob/master/tools/bin/), so you can check out the code yourself too and run that using:

./.syndesis/bin/syndesis minishift --install --full-reset --nodev --open

and then you can explore other options to specify a tag if you want.

Hope this gets you going!
Cheers,
--Kurt

Comment: Thanks, with --nodev it worked. Actually I've another one but will create another question